# php $_session not recognised in sub folders

Tags: php, session-cookies

I've got a user log in form which sets a cookie and enables members only content.

This works ok for all pages in the root folder of my site. I've confirmed the session variable exists etc.

However, when I try and check for the session variable in a script that is in a subfolder the session variable does not exist. I've looked at similar questions which suggest an answer and to add an '/' in the params.

This is my session start:

```
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60,'/');
```

This is before session_start()

In phpinfo the session cookie path is also set to '/'

The session exists at root level not for sub folders.

What have I missed and how can I resolve? I want to avoid passing a variable to the script if possible

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I solved this one!

In my script that was trying to access the session I did not have:

session_name(mysessionName)

or

session_start()

Apparently you need to re-initiate the session in the script in the other paths to get it to work then do session_start

session name must come before session start

Yay!!